# Recycle a floor possible?

Tags: star-wars-tiny-death-star

In the original Tiny Tower you could recycle a level if you didn't like it to get a better one.  It was like building a new level, but in an existing spot.  I would do that when I got something that never kept stock, or I just didn't like.  I can't seem to find a way to do that in Tiny Death Star.  I have a few levels that run out of stock in minutes all the time that I would rather just get rid of and put something else in, is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I have scowered Tiny Death Star, and *as of version 1.1.2144* it looks like **you cannot recycle a floor**.   The only way to attempt at getting another floor would be to delete the game and start over.